# Wordpress(PHP): Page not found title but content is there

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a class that registers a new endpoint, rewrites rules and then flushes it. It works perfectly except that it also gives a 404 error, making the page title "page not found" and adding some css which I dont want. I need to make it so that it actually knows my page exists.

This is the class I wrote:

```
<?php

use Jigoshop\Helper\Render as RenderCore;
use Jigoshop\Frontend\Page\PageInterface;
use Jigoshop\Integration\Helper\Render;


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

class twizo_Jigoshop_TFASettings implements PageInterface
{
    function __construct()
    {
        Render::addLocation('twizo-verification', __DIR__);
        add_action('init', function () {
        add_rewrite_endpoint("twizo-verification", EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES | 
EP_PERMALINK);
        add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', function ($rewrite) {
            $mySettings = [
                '^account/twizo-verification/?$' => 'index.php? 
pagename=twizo-verification'
            ];
            $rewrite->rules = $mySettings + $rewrite->rules;
            return $rewrite->rules;
        });
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    });
    add_filter('jigoshop.frontend.page_resolver.page', function ($args) {
        global $wp_query;
        if ($wp_query->query['pagename'] == 'twizo-verification') {
            return $this;
        }
        return $args;
    });
}

public function action()
{
    $this->renderTFASettings();
}

public function render()
{
}

public function renderTFASettings()
{
    add_action('jigoshop\template\shop\content\before', function () {        
        echo '<h1>My account &raquo; 2FA Settings</h1>';
    });
    add_action('jigoshop\template\shop\content\after', function() {
        echo '<br><a href="./" class="btn btn-default">Go back to My 
account</a>';
    });   

    switch(get_template()) {
        case "twentyfifteen":
            RenderCore::output('layout/twentyfifteen', [
                'content' => Render::get('twizo-verification', 'tfa- 
   settings-body', array())
            ]);
        break;
        case "twentysixteen":
            RenderCore::output('layout/twentysixteen', [
                'content' => Render::get('twizo-verification', 'tfa- 
   settings-body', array())
            ]);
        break;
        case "twentyseventeen":
            RenderCore::output('layout/twentyseventeen', [
                'content' => Render::get('twizo-verification', 'tfa- 
   settings-body', array())
            ]);
        break;
        default: 
            RenderCore::output('layout/default', [
                'content' => Render::get('twizo-verification', 'tfa- 
   settings-body', array())
            ]);
        break;
    }

    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Are there any error messages? If you use apache, check the apache error log

Comment: @TK nop, no errors in the apache error log

Comment: Can't find any other errors either. Only status code 404. I assume my endpoint is registered only after the page is looked for but I don't get how that could happen.